# Convert String "sin(pi*cos(pi*x*y))" to double

Tags: java, parsing

( I'm beginner )

double x = 0.5;
double y = 0.3;

```
    String[]normal = {"x","y","cos","sin","avg"};
    String[]complex = {"cos","sin","avg"};
    char coordinate = (char) (new Random().nextInt(2) + 'x');

    String result = "";


    if(levels == 1){
         String value1 = (normal[new Random().nextInt(normal.length)]);

         if (value1.equals("sin") ||value1.equals("cos")){
             result = value1 + "( pi *" + coordinate + ")";
            }
         else if(value1.equals("avg")){
             result = value1 + "(" + coordinate + "," + coordinate + ")" ;
         }
         else{
             result = value1 ;
            }
    }else{
            String value = (complex[new Random().nextInt(complex.length)]);
            if((value.equals("sin") ||value.equals("cos"))&&levels!=0 ){
                result = value + "( pi *" + createFunction(levels - 1) + ")";

            }
             else if(value.equals("avg")&& levels !=0){
                 result = value +"(" + createFunction (levels - (levels-1)) + "," + createFunction (levels - (levels-1)) + ")" ;

            }
            else if(value.equals("avg")&& levels ==2){
                result = value + "(" + createFunction (levels - 1) + "," + coordinate + ")" ;

            }
            else{
             result = value ;
            }


        }


        return result; 

    }
```

double  functions = ....................... ;

result will be  "sin(pi*cos(pi*x*y))" in String

how to calculate this string and keep in double functions

Comment: elaborate: the user inputs the string  "sin(pi*cos(pi*x*y))" where x and y are numbers and you must evaluate it? or just x and y are inputed?

Comment: `I know how to calculate "sin(pi*cos(pi*x*y))" and print it.` Maybe you should post the evidence of this, and we will help you keep it as a double.

Comment: add this .tostring();

Answer (score 1):

You are asking how to parse a string containing an arbitrary expression and then evaluate it to get a floating-point result.

That is quite difficult, requiring an expression parser, to convert the string into an expression tree, and an expression tree evaluator, to actually calculate the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy) scripts. The trick is to evaluate your input as a Java-like expression:

```
public final class Test{
    private static GroovyShell createMathShell() {
        GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell();

        shell.evaluate("" +
            "cos = {double x -> Math.cos(x)}\n" +   // predefine functions as lambda
            "sin = {double x -> Math.sin(x)}\n" +   // expressions
            "pi = Math.PI\n"                        // define pi
        );
        return shell;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GroovyShell shell = createMathShell();

        // set values
        shell.setVariable("x", 0);
        shell.setVariable("y", 1);

        // evaluate
        double result = (Double) shell.evaluate("sin(pi*cos(pi*x*y))"); 

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Executing this code will print:

```
1.2246467991473532E-16
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be wise to initialise a `double` and directly write the value into that variable.

```
Double answer = ....;
```

When you need the original value, just use the variable `answer`. When you need it as a string, just use:

```
String answer_string = String.valueOf(answer);
```

Or, for example:

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf(answer));
```

Answer (score 0):

Math.sin and Math.cos methods will accept double values, and return a double. Simply write a method taking as arguments x and y to return the formula:

```
double myAlgorithm( double x, double y){
return Math.sin(Math.PI*Math.cos(Math.PI*x*y))
}
```

This will work passing x and y as int as it will be casted implicitly to double

```
double myAlgorithm( int x, int y){
return Math.sin(Math.PI*Math.cos(Math.PI*x*y))
}
```

And, if you want to pass Strings instead of types:

```
double myAlgorithm( String x, String y){
return Math.sin(Math.PI*Math.cos(Math.PI*(Double.parseDouble(x).doubleValue())*(Double.parseDouble(y).doubleValue())))
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do it:

```
Double.valueOf(string);
```

Comment: No, it won't. See the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29).